# jsonobject cannot be converted with multiple input possibilities

Tags: android, json

i made a asynctask routine to comunicate to all my webservices that looks as follows:

```
  protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {

String parameterString = params[0];

        // effectieve http request met de parameters toegevoegd
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet aanvraag = new HttpGet(server + parameterString);

// foutanalyse van de http request
try
{
    HttpResponse antwoord = client.execute(aanvraag);
    StatusLine statuslijn = antwoord.getStatusLine();
    int statuscode = statuslijn.getStatusCode();
    if(statuscode != 200){
        Log.i("statuscode verzending", "statuscode= "+ statuscode);
        return null;
    }

    InputStream jsonStream = antwoord.getEntity().getContent();
    BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(jsonStream));
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String lijn;

    while((lijn = reader.readLine())!= null){
        builder.append(lijn);

    }

    String jsonData = builder.toString();

    // hier beginnen we met de json data te ontmantelen
    JSONArray json = new JSONArray(jsonData);



    String[] data = new String[35];

    Log.i("jsonparser", "lengte geretourde data " + json.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) 
    {
        data[i] = json.getString(i).toString();
    }


    return data;

}
catch (ClientProtocolException e){

    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e){

    e.printStackTrace();
}
 catch (JSONException e) {

e.printStackTrace();
  }
        return null;
    }
```

i use the routine everytime i connect to a webservice for my app, (i have about 15 of them)
all these webservices are made (and used) by the programs my software supplier made

now i would like to connect to them with my android app
some of them are working
others don't
what i found out already in my search for this failure:

some jsondata is returned in the form of:

```
    [
  "42416",
  " ",
   " ",
  " "
    ]
```

other webservices return data as:

```
    true
```

but the ones i am strugling with the most are looking like:

```
    {
   "z00": "1 ",
   "z01": 10000,
   "z02": "18/06/2010",
   "z03": "A",
   "z04": "0000",
   "z05": 7735,
   "z06": "VANNUYSE BVBA",                                                                                           
   "z07": "DEEFA",
   "z08": 17170,
   "z09": "AFLEVEREN HELI  IN GEBRUIK",
   "z10": "0000",
   "z11": "8770    ",
   "z12": "INTER                  ",
   "z13": "HELI                ",
   "z14": "CPCD25 - C240       ",
   "z15": "48182               ",
   "z16": "",
   "z17": "N",
   "z18": "0030",
   "z19": 0,
   "z20": "X",
   "z21": "                              ",
   "z22": "J",
   "z23": "",
   "z24": 0,
   "z25": "22/06/2010",
   "z26": 16854,
   "z27": 0,
   "z28": "AFLEVEREN IN GEBRUIK",
   "z29": "               "
   }
```

how should i form my asynctask routine so she is able to work for all routines?

because my routine works fine now for the first type of data but at 3th type i get an error (didn't tried yet for 2nd type) :

```
JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

thanks already for al your help guys

Comment: As the error says 3rd output is not a jsonArray, it is a jsonObject. You have to write:    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonData);

Comment: can i make for example: if jsondata = jsonobject(.....)else();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know what(jsonObject or jsonArray) is coming, you may try something like this:

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
    // handle jsonObject 
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // Try to parse it to a JSONAray. 
    // Also you can check the exception message here to determine if jsonArray conversion is wanted
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonData);
        // handle jsonArray             
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // something which is not JsonObject or JsonArray! 
    }
}
```

Or try this:

```
Object jsonAsObject = new JSONTokener(jsonData).nextValue();

if (jsonAsObject instanceof JSONObject) {
    // it is JSONObject
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonAsObject;  
} else if (jsonAsObject instanceof JSONArray) {
    // it is JSONArray
    JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonAsObject;
}
```